# Debian virtualenv location

Tags: linux, debian, www-data, virtualenv

I have a question that I would appreciate some help with. I want to run a number of sites from my debian server, each with their own virtualenv.

Should I be creating my virtualenv in the `www-data` or `/home/<user_name>/` directory?

Alternatively, could I do something like this:

- Put my virtualenv in `/home/<user_name>/<site_name>`
- Put my sites code in `www-data/<site_name>`

Thank you for any information you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a matter of preference and convention than anything else. On Debian systems, I tend to keep everything web-app-related under `/var/www/<site_name>`. If users expect to be able to access that directory, I drop a symbolic link to it under their `/home/<user_name>` directory. This keeps things neatly separated but accessible and would allow you to change parts of the structure later (eg: moving the web site storage) without moving/reconfiguring everything.

Comment: Is it right to have virtualenv's under the var/www though?

Comment: There isn't really a 'right' and 'wrong' as long as you're careful to not expose your site's code to the public. Separating code from the virtualenv would certainly be easiest way to accomplish that.